# how to find the maximum salary of employees in a specific department

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I have a table named `SalaryTable` containing salaries of employee in various departments:

```
dept_id    name   salary
12          a      100
13          b      200
12          c      300
14          d      400
12          e      500
13          f      600
```

I need to find the maximum salary of each department with given department id AND the name of that person along with maximum salary.

I am using the following sql query for this

```
select dept_id, name, max(salary)
from SalaryTable
group by salary
```

But the above code is giving me error: 
`dept_id must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause`

I am able to get the following table easily with this below query:

```
select dept_id, max(salary) as max_salary
from SalaryTable
group by salary 

dept_id          max_salary
12                  500
13                  600
14                  400
```

but I also need the name of that person as:
**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

```
dept_id     name     max_salary
12           e       500
13           f       600
14           d       400
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be learning SQL, so you can build on what you have.  The following gets the maximum salary:

```
select dept_id, max(salary)
from SalaryTable
group by dept_id;
```

You can use this as a subquery, to get all matching names:

```
select st.*
from SalaryTable st join
     (select dept_id, max(salary) as max_salary
      from SalaryTable
      group by dept_id
     ) std
     on st.dept_id = std.dept_id and
        st.salary = std.max_salary
```

Comment: the requirement is to get all the employees and as the problem statement suggests to get only employees with maximum salary.

Answer (score 1):

use correlated subquery

```
select dept_id, name, salary
from SalaryTable a 
   where salary =(select max(salary) from SalaryTable b where a.dept_id=b.dept_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

To be exact:

```
SELECT dept_id, NAME, salary FROM SalaryTable a 
WHERE salary =(SELECT MAX(salary) FROM SalaryTable b WHERE a.dept_id=b.dept_id) 
ORDER BY dept_id;
```

Also see try by joins because see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)

**Remember:** Whatever you put in between `select` and `from` in single sql statement that must be used in the `group by` clause (That's what your error says!).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
select s.* from SalaryTable s
where not exists (
  select 1 from SalaryTable 
  where dept_id = s.dept_id and salary > s.salary
)
order by s.dept_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=73ddd0b21211a5956024684943adf393).
Results:

```
> dept_id | name | salary
> ------: | :--- | -----:
>      12 | e    |    500
>      13 | f    |    600
>      14 | d    |    400
```